# Object becomes None when using a context manager

Tags: python, with-statement

Why doesn`t this work:

```
class X:
    var1 = 1
    def __enter__(self): pass
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback): pass

with X() as z:
    print z.var1
```

I get:

```
print z.var1
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'var1'
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Change the definition of `X` to

```
class X(object):
    var1 = 1
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass
```

`with` assigns the return value of the `__enter__()` method to the name after `as`.  Your `__enter__()` returned `None`, which was assigned to `z`.

I also changed the class to a new-style class (which is not critical to make it work).

Comment: For more information see PEP 343 [link](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) which describes the syntax quite nicely

Answer (score 9):

See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typecontextmanager.html) for context managers:

> `__enter__(   )` Enter the runtime context and return either this object or
>   another object related to the runtime
>   context. The value returned by this
>   method is bound to the identifier in
>   the as clause of with statements using
>   this context manager. An example of a
>   context manager that returns itself is
>   a file object. File objects return
>   themselves from `__enter__()` to allow
>   `open()` to be used as the context
>   expression in a with statement.
>
> An example of a context manager that
>   returns a related object is the one
>   returned by
>   `decimal.Context.get_manager()`. These
>   managers set the active decimal
>   context to a copy of the original
>   decimal context and then return the
>   copy. This allows changes to be made
>   to the current decimal context in the
>   body of the with statement without
>   affecting code outside the with
>   statement.

Your `__enter__` method doesn't return anything, which is the same as returning `None`.

Answer (score 4):

The function you've defined between 'with' and 'as' must have and only have one return value. 'with' will pass the value to its built-in method `__enter__()`.

A class-type object in Python will not return any value if not defined when you called it.

Similarly, if you called a class-type object with its method that returns nothing, it will also throw out exception.

You can't write like this:

```
with open('file.txt').readlines() as lines:
```

This generated two return values, and it's even not allowed to pass to one variable in Python.

But this is good to use:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```